# prime number with sum and three loop

Tags: java

I tried to solve this code but really I cant .. I don't have any result of it ... if somembody can help , this code works but without result !! :

```
public class Primenumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10000;
        long sum = 0;
        loop:
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = j; k < n; k++) {
                    if (i == j * k) {
                        continue loop;
                    }
                }
            }
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println("该整数之内的所有素数之和是：" + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "solve this code"? The code appears to be correct, do you want to understand what it does?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: there is no result after compiling the program , there should be result of it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is looping on about `n^3` iterations (a little less). No wonder it doesn't go to the end when you pass a big `n`.

You can "make it work" by changing

```
n = 10000;
```

to

```
n = 1000;
```

then the result is

```
该整数之内的所有素数之和是：76127
```

In short your code seems to work fine, you just have to look for a more efficient algorithm for big `n`.

Comment: the result should be the sum of all prime number below 10000, not 1000 , whats my mistake ?

Comment: It works, it's just too slow for big values of n.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into detail of advanced sieve algorithms:

- You only need to find divisors lower or equals than `sqrt(i)`. (If an integer `j>sqrt(i)` 
  divides `i`, there exist another integer `k<sqrt(i)` that also divides `i`.)
- You can discard (i.e. not check) even divisors other that 2. (If an even integer divides `i`, then `2` divides `i`, and you have already tested that before)
- You can discard divisors that you know that are not prime (i.e. earlier values of `i` that you found that were prime). If an integer `j` divides `i`, either `j` is prime, or `j=p*m` (where `p` is prime, and `p` divides `i`).
- The inner loop is unnecesary (you are replacing a division by a brute-force search of the quotient). Instead, check whether `i%j==0` (i.e. if the remainder of `i` divided by `j` is zero).